# jQuery slideToggle, slide up other elements

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Hi I am using jQuery slide toggle on two nested ul's, however when I click on the secondary ul the other ul doesn't slide up.

How can I get jQuery to detect the correct one and slide this up?

I Have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2rktyn1/) as an example of what I'm doing. Any suggestions as to what I can do differently?

Code example:

```
<ul class="top-category four columns">
    <li class="filter-title">Filter by: Blog Categories <span class="icon-arrow-down3"></span>

        <ul class="child-category">
            <li class="filter-item">
                <input type="checkbox" id="tag_278" name="blog_categories[]" class="fintech siteset-checkbox" value="FinTech" data-name="FinTech">FinTech</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="top-category four columns">
    <li class="filter-title">Filter by: Staff <span class="icon-arrow-down3"></span>

        <ul class="child-category">
            <li class="filter-item">
                <input type="checkbox" id="tag_283" name="staff[]" class="jan_stannard siteset-checkbox" value="Jan Stannard" data-name="Jan Stannard">Jan Stannard</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
  $( ".filter-title" ).click(function() { 
         $(this).children().nextAll('.child-category').slideToggle();
  });
```

css

```
 .child-category {display:none}
```

Comment: I suppose it's working alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( ".filter-title" ).click(function() { 
     var child = $(this).children('.child-category') ,
         rest = $('.child-category:visible').not(child);

     child.slideToggle(); //toggle current one
     rest.slideUp(); //close the rest

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLjx9r1d/1/)

Comment: What is the reason for down-voting a perfectly working answer?

Comment: its not perfectly working, infact instead of using nextAll you've changed to first. you clearly haven't tested properly if you had you'd see it works in the exact same way as my example.

Comment: Your example is not working. If you toggle the first category and you click on the second title, the first category gets hidden. .nextAll is used wrong in your example. My example works as intended as you can check on the fiddle I have linked. I have used .first() just for performance reasons. You can omit it if you want.

Comment: "Your example is not working" which is why i posted a question. moot point. delete your answer if your that concerned or actually answer properly. your first answer which literally try this: and a line of code which works EXACTLY like my example. if you don't like the down vote, well your life isn't over. get on with it.

Comment: Sorry for this. I now understand what you meant. You want when you click on one category the rest of them to close. I will update my answer.

Comment: no problem. thanks for the help thats a better solution. upvoted and accepted

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 $(".filter-title").click(function () {
     $('.child-category:visible').stop(true, true).slideToggle(); // <---add this line
     $(this).find('.child-category').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
 });
```

Comment: if I click the filter-title twice it toggles out of control

Comment: you can add `.stop(true, true)` before `.slideToggle();`

Comment: @g_9020 well congrats if you get your issue solved but in the fiddle you posted the css of your child ul is not letting the second one clicked that way.